# JavaScript TypeError null on click or eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hei, I'm try to add an eventListener on a `<li>` element that contains an image and in console I see that every time it comes null. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```js
document.getElementById("rock").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div id="container" class="playerContainer">
  <p>Player</p>
  <li id="rock" title="rock"><img src="images/rock.PNG" alt="Rock"></li>
  <li id="papper"><img src="images/papper.PNG" alt="Papper"></li>
  <li id="scissors"><img src="images/scissors.PNG" alt="Scissors"></li>
</div>
```

Comment: @Andy, that wouldn't result in it being null, that would result in an error being thrown

Comment: Please state the exact error message.

Comment: Executing the code snippet shows that it's logging the click event just fine, so it must be something else. Can you add some more context, replicating the error in the code snippet?

Comment: By moving the script tag to the bottom it seems to work. Can you tell me please why is this happening? I mean what's the logic from behind? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @35Zoll When your script is ececuted in the head, the DOM elements do not exist yet. You can either wrap your code in a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event listener, or execute the code after the elements it accesses are available.

Comment: @ChrisG, yes, helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: Just FYI, `Does this answer your question? *link to dupe*` is a standard comment automatically posted by stackoverflow when you flag a question as dupe. I usually edit it into `Duplicate: *link to dupe*` but was too lazy here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must check if you are adding the eventListener after the element is created. Your code is by default executed top to botton, so if you create your event listener script befere the element gets rendered it will not be found.

A Solution would be to sctructure your code like the example bellow:

```
<div id="container" class="playerContainer">
    <p>Player</p>
    <li id="rock" title="rock"><img src="images/rock.PNG" alt="Rock"></li>
    <li id="papper"><img src="images/papper.PNG" alt="Papper"></li>
    <li id="scissors"><img src="images/scissors.PNG" alt="Scissors"></li>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("rock").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
console.log(e);
});
</script>
```

And this sould trigger your event listener fine.

Comment: This question is already correctly marked as a duplicate, please don't post answers to dupes.